# Inserting and Displaying images within the TinyMCE content editor in PHP site  

Tags: tinymce

I am currently using tinyMCE to edit content within my site and I am looking for a way display an image within the tinyMCE once it has been uploaded to the site.

Note: I am not looking for a means to upload an image directly into tinyMCE. I am looking for the tinyMCE command which would allow me to display an image within the content in the editor after I have uploaded it.

Thanks

Comment: -1 for adding a bounty but not responding to offer of help to wipe out the problem

Answer (score 4):

You could insert a regular img-tag inside tinymce using a custom plugin or using [the setup parameter](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3asetup) in your tinymce init. The src should refer to the html location of the image to be uploaded. As soon as the image is available the image will become visible on next reload of the editors content. If you need further assistance feel free to ask.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I wanted something similarly to the Tiny MCE plugin used in Joomla whereby the image displays instantly after insertion and not after reloading the page

Comment: to get this effect you could also use editor.save() and then mceRemoveControl and mceAdddControl

Answer (score 0):

After successfull uploaded you have the source of the image (img_src). Now you need to add it to the editor like this

```
tinymce.activeEditor.insertContent('<img alt="photo" src="' + img_src + '"/>');
```